# The construct: [subject] "approximates" [something] to [something else]

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/approximate#american-english-2-1-1) provides this example of "approximate" as a verb:

> **to come near in ​quality, ​amount, ​value, or ​character:**
>
> The ​painting only approximated the ​mountain ​landscape.

Similarly, [Oxford](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/approximate_2) provides this example:

> **approximate to something:**
>
> His story approximates to the facts that we already know.

**My question:**

Adding my own subjects (for instance **"the artist"** and **"the author"**), can I use **"the story"** and **"the painting"** as objects, while keeping the meaning exactly as is in both sentences? Here are the sentences as I *want* them to sound like:

I.

> The **​artist** only approximated the painting to the ​mountain
> ​landscape.

II.

> The **author** manages to approximate his story to the facts we already
> know.

My suspicion is that I have changed the meaning, but I am not sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is to decide whether ***approximates*** requires "to", and my best-usage detector suggests that the "to" is not very good.

So a sentence like "The author approximates the story as it is well-known in history books." sounds rather better than "The author approximates [via their writing, etc] to the story as it is well-known in history books."

I suspect "... approximates [object] to [object]" is not a common usage, irrespective of any slight meaning change.

Comment: Whether or not you think the "approximates to" sounds good, it appears to be a valid usage with a different meaning that I had never heard of either. It's in the dictionary the OP cited and the first dictionary I checked also has a line about it (but no example sentence).